# Error when using setState to set an empty array to object property ( react Hooks)

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, react-hooks, destructuring

im having problems with this line:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (AplicationsList) {
    setDetail({ ...Detail, components: AplicationsList });
  }
}, [AplicationsList]);
```

When AplicationsList its an empty array [] it gives me an error, like Detail is then undefined. But when its not empty works fine...
either if the array its empty or not I have to set the value  on components attribute of Detail.
Any idea why this is happening?

This is the error I'm facing in the  child component that depends on "Detail" passed as props:[cannot read property map of undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwdQM.png)

And I get this react warning:
[can't perform a react state update in an unmounted component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4irA.png)

I've tried with this functional update but still is giving me the same errors:
setDetail(Detail => ({
...Detail,
components: AplicationsList,
}));

Comment: If the new state is computed using the previous state, [React recommends using a functional update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) (where you pass a function to the setter). Have you tried using this variant? `setDetail((detail) => ({ ...detail, components: applicationsList }))` Could you also add the exact error you are facing (including stacktrace) to the question?

Comment: Going off of what @AbhishekGowda28 said, check the length of the array in the conditional. I think a variable assigned to an empty array evaluates truthy.

Answer (score 0):

From you question, I understand `Details` is an object and `AplicationsList` is an array.

I think you have set the state of details this way or similar to this
`const [Details, setDetails] = useState();`. The problem with this is the initial value of Details is undefined and you are trying to destructure undefined. Instead set it as `const [Details, setDetails] = useState({});`

In useEffect you are checking if `AplicationsList` is empty, but `if(AplicationsList)` return true even for empty array. So check for the length instead, `if(AplicationsList.length > 0)`

**Suggestion:** It's good practice to have the state variable name to be of lowerCase and follow camleCase format to name variable. Instead of `Details` and `ApplicationsList`, its good you rename to `details` and `applicationsList`.

Comment: Precisely, I want to set the Detail.components to an empty array when AplicationsList  its an empty array. To be shown later as "There are no components in this Detail". I've tried with: `const [Details, setDetails] = useState({})`; and the error keeps appearing, also with `setDetail((detail) => ({ ...detail, components: applicationsList }))`. Looks like aplicationsList its affecting not only the components attribute but all the detail object. @AbhishekGowda @3limin4t0r  Thanks for your help! Im really stuck here

Comment: I've found the error! In the hook Im using to store values from api, I had a [] seted to the result, so, when the service returned [] it was no changes and the useEffect whas not executed! Thanks a lot